# How to bring back auto scroll in Chrome?

Tags: 13.10, google-chrome

How to bring back auto scroll in Chrome ?
I'm really addicted to this feature and I feel like I'm missing a hand browsing without this feature.
Can I do this in Chrome ?
I'm using Ubuntu 13.10.

Comment: I've found out. I have to use AutoScroll extension.

Comment: That was quick....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an [Autoscroll extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/autoscroll/occjjkgifpmdgodlplnacmkejpdionan):

[image: autoscroll]

After adding the extension, you might have to restart Chrome for the function to kick in.

Note that Chrome will, by default, continue running even if you have closed all open Chrome windows.

Make sure you have completely closed Chrome by checking that there is no Chrome icon in the top panel and/or that there are no Chrome processes in System Monitor.

Then, re-launch Chrome, and the extension will be working.